How to fix gcloud builds submit ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
I'm trying to submit a new container to gcloud, but when I run:
!gcloud builds submit --tag europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/[company]-website/[company]-containers/[company]-room 
(where you read [company] it's just to anonymise the company's name)
I get:
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit).
When checking the build logs I find:
2024-07-10 16:52:03.438 BST
ERROR
{
insertId: "4a63cf2a-055c-446d-ba37-6cfccd395851-178"
labels: {
build_step: "MAIN"
}
logName: "projects/[company]-website/logs/cloudbuild"
receiveTimestamp: "2024-07-10T15:52:03.582964367Z"
resource: {
labels: {
build_id: "4a63cf2a-055c-446d-ba37-6cfccd395851"
build_trigger_id: ""
project_id: "[company]-website"
}
type: "build"
}
severity: "INFO"
textPayload: "ERROR"
timestamp: "2024-07-10T15:52:03.438949941Z"
}

and:
2024-07-10 16:52:03.438 BST
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
{
insertId: "4a63cf2a-055c-446d-ba37-6cfccd395851-179"
labels: {
build_step: "MAIN"
}
logName: "projects/[company]-website/logs/cloudbuild"
receiveTimestamp: "2024-07-10T15:52:03.582964367Z"
resource: {
labels: {
build_id: "4a63cf2a-055c-446d-ba37-6cfccd395851"
build_trigger_id: ""
project_id: "[company]-website"
}
type: "build"
}
severity: "INFO"
textPayload: "ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1"
timestamp: "2024-07-10T15:52:03.438984011Z"
}

My project structure is:
[project_name]
|—- .venv
|    |—— ...
|
|—— app
|    |—— model
|    |     |—— ...
|    |
|    |—— __init__.py
|    |—— exception_handlers.py
|    |—— logger.py
|    |—— main.py
|    |—— middleware.py
|    |—— README.Docker.md
|    |—— room_matching.py
|
|—— build_container.ipynb
|—— docker-compose.yml
|—— Dockerfile
|—— poetry.lock
|—— pyproject.toml
|—— README.md

My Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11-buster AS builder

RUN pip install poetry==1.8.2

ENV POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=1 \
    POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/tmp/poetry_cache

WORKDIR /app

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
RUN touch README.md

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=$POETRY_CACHE_DIR poetry install --no-root

# The runtime image, used to just run the code provided its virtual environment
FROM python:3.11-slim-buster AS runtime

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/app/.venv \
    PATH="/app/.venv/bin:$PATH"

COPY --from=builder ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ${VIRTUAL_ENV}

COPY app ./app

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "app.main"]

and my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  api:
    build: ./app/
    image: [company]-room4-1
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/room_matching:ro

(also tried with build: . and build: /app/ instead of build: ./app/
I've checked questions such as this and this with no luck.
If anyone's able to help me I'll deeply appreciate it.
Thank you for your attention.
UPDATE
As requested, I'm sharing minimal code and steps/documents you are following to build and run your application.
main.py
# standard libraries
import os
from typing import Dict, Union

# 3rd party
from fastapi import FastAPI, status
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException
from uvicorn import run

# custom libraries
from app.exception_handlers import (
    http_exception_handler,
    request_validation_exception_handler,
    unhandled_exception_handler
)
from app.room_matching import check_match, check_health
from app.middleware import log_request_middleware

# type validation & sending arguments to room_match_scores
class HMR_input(BaseModel):
    original_room : str
    candidate_room : str

# init'ing the App
app = FastAPI()

# prep'ing Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) configs
origins = ["*"]
methods = ["*"]
headers = ["*"]

# activating CORS
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins= origins,
    allow_credentials= True,
    allow_methods= methods,
    allow_headers= headers
)

# init'ing middleware exception handlers
app.middleware("http")(log_request_middleware)
app.add_exception_handler(RequestValidationError, request_validation_exception_handler)
app.add_exception_handler(HTTPException, http_exception_handler)
app.add_exception_handler(Exception, unhandled_exception_handler)

# func to check health
@app.get("/")
def health():
    if check_health():
        return JSONResponse(
            status_code= status.HTTP_200_OK,
            content= {"status": "healthy"}
        )

    else:
        return JSONResponse(
            status_code= status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            content= {"status": "error"}
        )

# func to retrieve the room match
@app.post("/room_matching")
def get_matches(input: HMR_input)-> Dict[str, Union[str, float]]:
    """
    Function that recieves two room names, processes them, and
    retrieves an CrossEncoder model prediction of whether they're
    the same room ('match'), different ('no_match') or an upgrade
    ('upgrade').

    Args:
        input (HMR_input): a BaseModel (pydantic) collection of
        inputs & their types in order to compute the probability
        scores of being the same room, different, or an upgrade:

            original_room : str -> the room name we whish to
            check if it's a match against the other;

            candidate_room : str -> the name of the second room
            we want to check how it relates to the original.

    Returns:
        Dict[str, Union[str, float]]: a dictionary containing the
        model's prediction and the confidence that the model has
        that's not a match, match & upgrade.
    """
    # predicting if the rooms are or not a match
    matches = check_match(input.original_room, input.candidate_room)

    # organizing data to return
    results = {
        "prediction": matches[0],
        "no_match_confidence": matches[1][0],
        "match_confidence": matches[1][1],
        "upgrade_confidence": matches[1][2]
    }

    return results

When I'm at the [project_name] level (one level above "app", "Dockerfiler", etc), I run (in the terminal):
uvicorn app.main:app --reload

and everything works.
I then run:
docker build -t [company]-room-4_1 .

everything's seems fine, and if I follow with:
docker run [company]-room-4_1

It get's stuck here:
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

When opening the link I get a message indicating it can't connect to the server.
The reason I say it gets stuck there is that I've tried adding some print statements before each section of the code and only after I quit the app (through CTRL + C) they all get printed.
This is particularly weird as I'm using a version of PyTorch that produce a couple of warmings (but still work) when the app's loaded, and it shows that same warnings when I run the docker:
/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/transformers/utils/generic.py:441: UserWarning: torch.utils._pytree._register_pytree_node is deprecated. Please use torch.utils._pytree.register_pytree_node instead.
  _torch_pytree._register_pytree_node(
/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/transformers/utils/generic.py:309: UserWarning: torch.utils._pytree._register_pytree_node is deprecated. Please use torch.utils._pytree.register_pytree_node instead.
  _torch_pytree._register_pytree_node(

but these warnings come BEFORE the server's initiated.
While when I ran:
uvicorn app.main:app --reload

I got (you can also see the prints I've added):
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/Users/[user]/[folder]/[folder]/room-matching/containers/[company]-room4.1-failed']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [11906] using WatchFiles
*** IMPORTS ***
/Users/[user]/[folder]/[folder]/room-matching/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/utils/generic.py:441: UserWarning: torch.utils._pytree._register_pytree_node is deprecated. Please use torch.utils._pytree.register_pytree_node instead.
  _torch_pytree._register_pytree_node(
/Users/[user]/[folder]/[folder]/room-matching/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/utils/generic.py:309: UserWarning: torch.utils._pytree._register_pytree_node is deprecated. Please use torch.utils._pytree.register_pytree_node instead.
  _torch_pytree._register_pytree_node(
*** BASEMODEL ***
*** APP ***
*** HEALTH ***
*** ROOM MATCHING ***
INFO:     Started server process [11908]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.

One thing to notice here is that in one case the .venv python folder is 3.11 and the other is 3.12. As you'll be able to see below is that I had to change the Dockerfile so that's building from python3.12 instead of 3.11, and the final line to get to this point, now being:
FROM python:3.12-rc-buster AS builder

RUN pip install poetry==1.8.2

ENV POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=1 \
    POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/tmp/poetry_cache

WORKDIR /app

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
RUN touch README.md

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=$POETRY_CACHE_DIR poetry install --no-root

# The runtime image, used to just run the code provided its virtual environment
FROM python:3.12-rc-slim-buster AS runtime

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/app/.venv \
    PATH="/app/.venv/bin:$PATH"

COPY --from=builder ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ${VIRTUAL_ENV}

COPY app ./app

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

To apply this correctly I've change the pyproject.toml so that it reads python = "^3.12" where it previously read python = "^3.11", added uvicorn = "^0.30.1", ran poetry lock --no-update followed by poetry install, both without a hitch, but the warning remains with the 3.11 in the locally working ran with the uvicorn command, while it shows the 3.12 in the non-working docker build.
In any case If after this I run:
!gcloud builds submit --tag europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/[company]-website/[company]-containers/[company]-room

I still get the same error as before.
Thanks for you help and attention and let me know if you need more info.

Have you checked this thread? Also can you share cloudbuild.yaml file?

I have no cloudbuild.yaml file @RoopaM . Didn't see it in any reference I used to build this. I take it I need one?
Thank you,

If I'm understanding correctly, the cloudbuild.yaml file is used inlace of Docker commands of gcloud builds summit, correct? If so that's being taken care of by the build_container.ipynb, where one can read (among other things): # run to submit build
!gcloud builds submit --tag europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/[company]-website/[company]-containers/[company]-room
This was prepared by my predecessor

As per your comment, looks like you are using google colab. Have you tried on normal Google Cloud console/CLI or locally? Also if possible can you share logs by running gcloud builds log BUILD_ID

no, not using google colab. I am using the google cloud console/cli, just my predecessor left the commands for it prepared in a notebook.  And yes, I've tried to run them locally, same results. As for the logs, I'm sorry, but I do not have permissions to do so :(

Locally mean, Have you tried using Docker CLI to build your image?

I have. No problems with the build, but when running this version had a similar, if not identical "exited with non-zero status: 1" message (sorry, can't reproduce it now).
At this point I'm working on 2 different versions trying to fix this. Both build fine, the problem's when running.
One's giving me «ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main"."»
The other: «ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi'»
I think it's something to do with the directories and/or the setting up of the environment. I don't understand these behaviours :/

Can you share steps/documents you are following to build and run your application? If possible, can you share minimal code as well?

I've (hopefully) added the information you've requested in my latest update @RoopaM. Let me know if you need more, and thank you again for your help

In the meantime I realised I wasn't running the docker compose up, which solved the problem of running the docker locally. Now the only thing's the gcloud build submit to work
